# MusicBrainz API search provides different results from web page

Tags: lucene, musicbrainz

I'm trying to work with *MusicBrainz*'s API but I'm having some issues with the results of the *search* endpoint.

Let's have an example searching for *Who's Who? - SIZE020 - Klack (Mix Two)*

Searching from their site leads to [this page](https://musicbrainz.org/search?query=Who%27s%20Who%3F%20-%20SIZE020%20-%20Klack%20%28Mix%20Two%29&type=recording), with an almost correct first result (probably because the 100% correct infos are not on the database at all).

Using the API leads to different situations which are causing some issues.
I made some different attempts with no success, even if I think I know enough of *Lucene*'s syntax to write a successful query for this service.

- [Take 1](http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording?query=%22Who%27s%20Who?%20-%20SIZE020%20-%20Klack%20%28Mix%20Two%29%22) - empty results with the query *"Who's Who? - SIZE020 - Klack (Mix Two)"*
- [Take 2](http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording?query=Who%27s%20Who%3F%20-%20SIZE020%20-%20Klack%20%28Mix%20Two%29) - completely wrong results with the query *Who's+Who%3F+-+SIZE020+-+Klack+(Mix+Two)* (same result with the unescaped *?* character)
- [Take 3](http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording?query=%22Who%27s%22%20AND%20%22Who?%22%20AND%20%22SIZE020%22%20AND%20%22Klack%22%20AND%20%22Mix%22%20AND%20%22Two%22) - empty results with the query *"Who's" AND "Who?" AND "SIZE020" AND "Klack" AND "Mix" AND "Two"*

Now, I know that *SIZE020* shouldn't be in the query, but I don't want to deal with file names on client side so I'm just pushing the query to their service hoping that everything will work. And it works, but only if I query the service through their website, making me think that my query syntax is wrong and leaving me clueless.

Do you have any hint on why I get different results between website and xml API?

EDIT: as a side question, given a random file name, what's the better way to submit the query? I'm getting good result using the web version and submitting the typical mp3 filenames (like *artist_-_title_(version).mp3* but I'm not getting anything good from my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching via the web service always uses the "indexed search with advanced query syntax" search method, this can't be changed.

Comment: Is there any way to use it through the API too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question - the web service is the API.

Comment: Oh dear, I just misread. Does this mean that there's no way to have on the API the same resutls of the website?

Comment: Yes, there's no way to do that.